# Why is Python running a different script?

Tags: python

I'm in Windows and I have a script called `csv.py`, I recently installed Pandas, and created `anotherscript.py`. The only code I have under `anotherscript.py` is `import pandas`.

When I run `py anotherscript.py` all it is doing is running `csv.py`. I have renamed `csv.py` to something else and it is still getting called.

If I removed import pandas, it works. If I move `anotherscript.py` to a different folder it works fine. It looks like something is cached.

What am I missing???

**anotherscript.py**

`import pandas`

**cmd call and output**

```
C:\Users\*****>py anotherscript.py
0 634
1 Saturday, January  8, 2022
2 15:00 EST
.
.
.
<cal file created and uploaded>
```

**csv.py**

*This script scrapes a webpage and creates a calendar file*

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from ics import Calendar, Event
from datetime import datetime
import pytz
from ftplib import FTP
import ftplib
import urllib.request
import requests


response = requests.post("urlRetrated")
with open('u7.xlsx', 'wb') as s:
    s.write(response.content)

wb_obj = openpyxl.load_workbook('u7.xlsx') 
worksheet = wb_obj.active
data = []
c = Calendar()
EST = pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')


for count, row_cells in enumerate(worksheet.iter_rows(min_row=2,values_only=True)):
    for count, cell in enumerate(row_cells):
        data.append(cell)
        
    date_and_time = data[1] + " " + data[2].strip('EST ')
    game_datetime = datetime.strptime(date_and_time, '%A, %B %d, %Y  %H:%M')
    
    if 'SoccerTeam' in data[3]:
        data[3] = 'William'
    
    if 'SoccerTeam' in data[5]:
        data[5] = 'William'
    
    game_title  = data[3] + " Vs " + data[5]
    game_location = data[6]
    
    e = Event()
    e.name = game_title
    e.begin = game_datetime.replace(tzinfo=EST)
    e.location = game_location  
    e.created = datetime.today()
    c.events.add(e)
    with open('marcos.ics', 'w', newline='') as f:
        f.write(str(c))
        f.close()   
        
        
    for index, value in enumerate(data):
        print(index, value)
    data = []
        

user = '****'
pas = '*****'

try:
    ftp = ftplib.FTP('*****', user, pas)
    print(ftp.getwelcome())
    ftp.cwd('public_html')
    file = open('will.ics','rb')
    ftp.storbinary('STOR will.ics', file)
    file.close()
    ftp.quit()
except ftplib.error_perm as error:
    if error:
        print ('Login Failed')
```

Thanks

Comment: where are you runnin it? Pycharm? Notice next to the Play and Debug buttons that even if you are editing one file you might be running a different one

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki haha, I wish I could count the number of times pycharm trolled me like that.

Comment: lol, I'm running directly from command line in Windows

Comment: No idea. Only if you actually paste screenshots of both files then might be able to figure out!

Comment: Please include some code samples, so we can help more.

Comment: Done, and yes anotherscript.py only has ONE line